# Python script not getting executed when put on crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron-task

I have written a python script which is reading some logs and then writing the required info into a csv file.Its working fine if I execute it manually by python `myscript.py` .However when I m calling it through cron its not working.
I have tried:

```
* * * * * python /path/to/myscript.py
* * * * * /path/to/myscript.py
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py
```

After some failed attempts I put python `myscript.py` in a shell script and ran it manually,it worked but again in cron it did not.

Comment: _I have written a python script_ Where is your relevant code?

Comment: Whatever is in python script is not relevant. The problem is that the default shell for cron is not `/bin/bash`

Comment: I'll assume you use some form of linux. Is your python script executable? Did you put `#!/path/to/python` in the first line? (That would probably be `#!/usr/bin/python` in your case.)

Comment: Sorry but my crystal ball is out for repair. But perhaps could you start by logging the error or whatever your script outputs so you'd have a clue about what happens ?

Comment: @Alex Yes I made it executable and also added the shebang line

Comment: Is there any corresponding error message in `/var/log/syslog?`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo That is actually not true. If he uses relative paths, there's a chance that the script runs to a certain point but then throws an error.

Comment: @j4ck the difference is that `bash` sets up the environment for the user and changes directory to $HOME while in cron the default `sh` doesn't.

Comment: Huh. That's interesting. Cheers, I didn't know!

Comment: Try set your cron job as `* * * * * /path/to/python /path/to/myscript.py 2>&1 >> /tmp/myscript.log`.  Then see whether there are error messages in `/tmp/myscript.log` file after one minute.

Answer (score 0):

- Tpye "**which python**" (if you are using python3 or python3.6 then you need to use **which python3**)
- It will display python path : /bin/python.
- Set value in Cron job - * * * * * /bin/python

If you want to execute python file inside the bash script by help of cronjob. you should use full path of python (**Example:**/bin/python  /path of python file/file.py) inside of bash script.

Answer (score -1):

Default shell for cron is not `/bin/bash`, so you need to give the full path to Python executable.
Check the output of `which python`. On my machine it's `/usr/bin/python`.
Assuming this, your cron job entry should be:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py
```

Sometimes you want to use virtualenv or set some environment variables or change working directory before you run the script.
In that case it's handy to create a wrapper script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Change working directory
cd /path/to
# Activate Python virtual environment
source bin/activate
# Set some environment variable
export LOG_FILE_PATH="/var/log/whatever.log"
# Finally run your python script
python myscript.py
```

Given that you save the above script to `/path/to/myscript_wrapper.sh`, your cron job entry will look like:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/myscript_wrapper.sh
```

Comment: Also the second solution?

Comment: ..if you did try it already, you should have a log message, no? What does that say?

Comment: Haven't try the second approach yet. I am not exactly getting it.

Comment: Once again then. Cront is using `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`. With `/bin/sh` your default environment e.g. `.bashrc` is not loaded and also the working directory is not changed to your $HOME. This always causes headache you're experiencing. Just write the bash script I'm showing you. If you aren't using virtualenv and env vars, delete lines `source bin/activate` and `export LOG_FILE_PATH="/var/log/whatever.log"`, and start this wrapper script from cron and not python script directly.

Comment: `* * * * *  root(username) /path/to/myscript_wrapper.sh ` will it helps??

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you do not use any kind of relative paths inside your python script. This can cause your script to exit with an error.

So make sure that within your script you do not use `../to/something`, but instead `/path/to/something`.

ie

```
with open('../file.txt', 'r') as f:
```

should become

```
with open('/full/path/to/file.txt', 'r') as f:
```

Comment: Yeah I am using absolute path only.

Comment: Hardcoding absolute paths in Python scripts is not a good idea. Imagine you will deploy it to production server and you will see the error like `No such file or directory: /home/j4ck/...` right away, cause noramally you don't run services in production on behalf of your unix user and therefore all your service's code and relevant files will land in other directory than your home directory.

Comment: True, if it were such a case I'd still not recommend `..` - rather something like `os.abspath(__file__)`, and work from that instead. But I might just be branded by past troubles I've had with this and cron jobs, and I don't have much experience with deploying to foreign systems.

Comment: Now you're talking. You are 100% right - `os.abspath(__file__)` is the way to go in basic setup. However if one is using deployment automation tools, then these tools are responsible for passing correct command line arguments, environment variables or configuration files, so that the actual service gets all the information about paths, remote services and so on.